# How can I center the text that I have placed between two figures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabulary

I tried a few different ways of doing so using minipages and tabular but this is the result:

[image: Plot]

and here is the code:

```
    \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1]
    \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
    \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
    \draw[<->] (-2.6,0) -- (2.6,0) node[right] {$\Psi_1$};
    \draw[<->] (0,-2.6) -- (0,2.6) node[above left] {$\Psi_2$};
      
    \foreach \Point in {(-1.5,1.5), (-1.5,-1.5), (1.5,1.5), (1.5,-1.5), (0,2.12) , (0,-2.12), (2.12,0),      (-2.12,0)}{
    \node at \Point {\textbullet};}

    \draw[dashed,draw=blue!60] (0,0) ++(0:2.12) arc (0:360:2.12);
    \end{tikzpicture}& \textbf{\Large OR}&

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1]
    \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
    \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
    \draw[<->] (-2.6,0) -- (2.6,0) node[right] {$\Psi_1$};
    \draw[<->] (0,-2.6) -- (0,2.6) node[above left] {$\Psi_2$};
      
    \foreach \Point in {(-0.5,0.5), (-0.5,-0.5), (0.5,0.5), (0.5,-0.5), (0,2.12) , (0,-2.12), (2.12,0), (-2.12,0)}{
    \node at \Point {\textbullet};}

    \draw[dashed,draw=blue!60] (0,0) ++(0:2.12) arc (0:360:2.12);
    \draw[dashed,draw=blue!60] (0,0) ++(0:0.707) arc (0:360:0.707);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tabular}
```

The problem is that I want OR to be aligned with the x-axis. Is there a way to make it so? I tried minipages, center and tabular but none of them seem to work with tabular giving the best results so far. Any help?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I tried so just after the begin statement for each picture but it made no difference.

Comment: Yes, that throws up an error saying that there is an Unknown Function 'current'.

Comment: Oops, `(current bounding box.center)` is a coordinate.  (It is a lot easier to test thes things with a complete MWE.)

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: There's also the possibility of doing this in just one TikZ picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `(current bounding box.center)` is slightly off the axis due to labels, so I added a named coordinate at the origin.  Also, the baseline of `or` is not at the center, hense the `\raisebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcr}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1, baseline=(origin)]
    \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
    \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
    \draw[<->] (-2.6,0) -- (2.6,0) node[right] {$\Psi_1$};
    \draw[<->] (0,-2.6) -- (0,2.6) node[above left] {$\Psi_2$};
      
    \foreach \Point in {(-1.5,1.5), (-1.5,-1.5), (1.5,1.5), (1.5,-1.5), (0,2.12) , (0,-2.12), (2.12,0),      (-2.12,0)}{
    \node at \Point {\textbullet};}

    \draw[dashed,draw=blue!60] (0,0) ++(0:2.12) arc (0:360:2.12);
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}& 
    \textbf{\Large \raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\dp\strutbox-0.5\ht\strutbox}{OR}}&

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1, baseline=(origin)]
    \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
    \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
    \draw[<->] (-2.6,0) -- (2.6,0) node[right] {$\Psi_1$};
    \draw[<->] (0,-2.6) -- (0,2.6) node[above left] {$\Psi_2$};
      
    \foreach \Point in {(-0.5,0.5), (-0.5,-0.5), (0.5,0.5), (0.5,-0.5), (0,2.12) , (0,-2.12), (2.12,0), (-2.12,0)}{
    \node at \Point {\textbullet};}

    \draw[dashed,draw=blue!60] (0,0) ++(0:2.12) arc (0:360:2.12);
    \draw[dashed,draw=blue!60] (0,0) ++(0:0.707) arc (0:360:0.707);
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

It ocurred to me that the tabular really isn't doing anything except pushing you into the right margin.  There are a number of ways to avoid that, but for simplicity I simply widened the text area.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=6in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1, baseline=(origin)]
    \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
    \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
    \draw[<->] (-2.6,0) -- (2.6,0) node[right] {$\Psi_1$};
    \draw[<->] (0,-2.6) -- (0,2.6) node[above left] {$\Psi_2$};
      
    \foreach \Point in {(-1.5,1.5), (-1.5,-1.5), (1.5,1.5), (1.5,-1.5), (0,2.12) , (0,-2.12), (2.12,0),      (-2.12,0)}{
    \node at \Point {\textbullet};}

    \draw[dashed,draw=blue!60] (0,0) ++(0:2.12) arc (0:360:2.12);
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}\hfill
    \textbf{\Large \raisebox{-0.2\baselineskip}{OR}}\hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1, baseline=(origin)]
    \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
    \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
    \draw[<->] (-2.6,0) -- (2.6,0) node[right] {$\Psi_1$};
    \draw[<->] (0,-2.6) -- (0,2.6) node[above left] {$\Psi_2$};
      
    \foreach \Point in {(-0.5,0.5), (-0.5,-0.5), (0.5,0.5), (0.5,-0.5), (0,2.12) , (0,-2.12), (2.12,0), (-2.12,0)}{
    \node at \Point {\textbullet};}

    \draw[dashed,draw=blue!60] (0,0) ++(0:2.12) arc (0:360:2.12);
    \draw[dashed,draw=blue!60] (0,0) ++(0:0.707) arc (0:360:0.707);
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```